# How to re-use cucumber gherkin steps without adding custom suffixes?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to learn cucumber, gherkin and selenium all at the same time for the first time.  I want to be able to re-use steps for various `Given` and `And` statements.  I have an approach, but it doesn't feel right because I used unique suffixes in my gherkin language to avoid some compile time errors related to duplicate rules.

Below is a short example of what I did which currently works, but is not ideal.

```
// account.feature
Feature: Account

Scenario: Can access account
 Given Reset database with mock data
 And Login as admin ##and##
 When Go to account
 Then Confirm email exists

// automobile.feature
Feature: Automobile

Scenario: Can access automobile
 Given Login as admin
 When Go to first automobile
 Then Confirm automobile name exists

// LoginSteps.java
package StepDefinitions;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;

public class LoginSteps {
    
    public LoginSteps() throws Throwable {

    }
    
    @Given ("Reset database with mock data")
    public void resetDatabaseWithMockData() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://example.com/setup");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
    }
    @Given("Login as admin")
    public void givenLoginAdmin() throws Throwable {
       loginAdmin();
    }
      
    @And("Login as admin ##and##")
    public void andLoginAdmin() throws Throwable {
       loginAdmin();
    }
      
    public void loginAdmin() throws Throwable {
        // login as admin code
    }
}
```

In short, I have two feature files `account.feature` and `automobile.feature`.  I expect `account.feature` to fire first followed by `automobile.feature`.  Notice that both feature files require you to `Login as admin`, but only the `account.feature` requires me to reset the database with some mock data.  Hence, in `account.feature`, I have a `Login as admin ##and##`, and in `automobile.feature`, I simply have `Login as admin`.

This doesn't feel right to me.  My overall objective is that i want to have several `*.feature` files that run their tests against a `mock data set1`, then another set of feature files that run their tests again a `mock data set 2`.

Can anyone tell me if there's a better way to achieve my results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle you should design your tests to be independent from each other. This may mean logging in for each scenario. This may mean re-starting your application for each scenario. This may mean creating fresh data for each scenario.

This may seem wasteful, especially if you have written manual test scripts before, but with automation it should be fast enough that you can afford the independent test executions.

So something like this:

```
Given a new tennant of automobile website 
And a new account "admin" with the admin role
And a registrered automobile "Ford 1"
When I the "admin" opens the automobile page
Then the automobile page contains a "Ford 1".
```

This is assuming the automobile website is multi-tennant. If not, you may have to start a new application instead for each scenario.

Comment: OK, i'll restructure and redesign my tests such that "create fresh data" step is performed once and once once prior to the execution of account.feature and and automobile.feature (ie. try to find a way to group account.feature and automobile.feature into a "suite" that share the same set up)

Comment: There is no "before feature" hook. So that won't work. Try to avoid the need to insert stub data through the database in the first place. The database is an implementation detail of the system. Try using its public API instead.

Comment: My definition of "create fresh data" is 1. `HTTP POST <url of database>?datasetname=whatever`  2. The server then does a `mysql import < whatever`.   I was hoping that selenium, cucumber, or gherkin has something like "1. Create fresh data.  2. Run account.feature OR run automobile.feature".  I'll keep researching to see if i'm approaching this all wrong.

Comment: Try and do it without ever loading data in the database except for the bare minimum. Also have a look at https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/ socialable test is the idea I'm going for.